# Populating a table from a view as view is too slow. Is there a better method for doing this in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view in Oracle which runs too slowly to use in various queries, and so I populate a table from the view and then periodically refresh all the data in the view from the table.

Is there a better method of doing this in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about [materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10706/repmview.htm#REPLN265)? You can adjust a materialized view so it will be updated on its own. Also you can add indexes to materialized view to increase performance.

Comment: Excellent - this looks like it does exactly what I need. The Oracle documentation is a bit heavy for simple use of the feature though.

Comment: To get started read Oracle Concepts, this is essential info about oracle database